# no attribute for sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql but files exist

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to access `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.UUID()`
but I am getting the error `module sqlalchemy.dialects has no attribute postgresql`.

which is surprising because I can see that the folder for postgressql exists at

```
~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql
```

so why cant I access that part of the module.

when I run `dir(sqlalchemy.dialects)` I get the following.

`['__all__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '_auto_fn',
 '_translates',
 'plugins',
 'registry',
 'util']`

im running
python 3.7.5
sqlalchemy 1.3.15
psycopg2 2.8.5

Comment: `from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql; postgresql.UUID()`

Comment: yes that works thank you. You have no idea how much time I spend on that

Comment: I was doing `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgres` instead of `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql`